# Como filtrar actividades en getstream segun el estado de la actividad?

Tags: python

*Estoy tratando de **filtrar** actividades por **getstream** segun el `status` de la actividad*

quiero mostrar todos las actividades que tengan status=1

```
result = user_feed_1.get(limit=5, offset=5)
```

ejemplo:

```
result_sin_filtro:[{'actor': '1',
  'foreign_id': 'e1d5a924',
  'id': 'e1d5a924',
  'message': '',
  'object': '1',
  'origin': 'user:1',
  'status': 3,
  'target': '',
  'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 21, 28, 10, 860778),
  'url': ''
  'verb': 'images'},{'actor': '2',
  'foreign_id': '123d1cas',
  'id': '123d1cas',
  'message': '',
  'object': '1',
  'origin': 'user:2',
  'status': 1,
  'target': '',
  'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 21, 28, 10, 860778),
  'url': ''
  'verb': 'images'}]


result_con_filtro:[{'actor': '2',
      'foreign_id': '123d1cas',
      'id': '123d1cas',
      'message': '',
      'object': '1',
      'origin': 'user:2',
      'status': 1,
      'target': '',
      'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 21, 28, 10, 860778),
      'url': ''
      'verb': 'images'}]
```

**RECUPERANDO ACTIVIDADES**

> documentacion : Las actividades en el feed se ordenan en un UUID en función del tiempo. Recomendamos paginar usando id_lt . Esto funciona mucho mejor que la paginación tradicional basada en desplazamiento. La lista completa de parámetros admitidos se incluye a continuación.

```
# Get activities from 5 to 10
result = user_feed_1.get(limit=5, offset=5)

# Get the 5 activities added after last_activity 
result = user_feed_1.get(limit=5, id_lt=last_activity.id)

# Get the 5 activities added before last_activity 
result = user_feed_1.get(limit=5, id_gt=last_activity.id)

# Get activities sorted by rank (Ranked Feeds Enabled):
result = user_feed_1.get(limit=5, ranking="popularity")

# Get first 5 activities and enrich them with reactions and collections
result = user_feed_1.get(
    limit=5, enrich=True, reactions={"counts": True, "recent": True},
)
```

*Si pueden ayudarme*